# VMware Fusion 5 Ignoring dhcpd.conf

Tags: networking, static-ip, ifconfig, vmware-fusion

I'm trying to set a static IP for my CentOS 6.4 VM that I'm running via VMware Fusion 5.

Steps I took:

- ran ifconfig, copied HWaddr
- shut down VM.
- added to the end of /Library/Preferences/VMware\ Fusion/vmnet8/dhcpd.conf (after "####### VMNET DHCP Configuration. End of “DO NOT MODIFY SECTION” #######" the following (vmname in place of vmnamehere and hwaddr in place of xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx)

  ```
  host vmnamehere {
      hardware ethernet xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;
      fixed-address 192.168.115.50;
  }
  ```
- restarted my mac
- booted up VM

Now when I run ifconfig it remains 172.16.49.143, which it was before this.

Did I miss a step here?

Edit: [Source for instructions](http://andrewelkins.com/linux/vmware-fusion-5-set-static-ip-address/).

Comment: If you wouldn't mind commenting why you're down-voting that would be great. Just trying to figure something out, without feedback I'm likely to ask a "stupid" question again.

Comment: Thank you. I thought serverfault was the right domain, I'll know for next time.